# Store numbers into user-defined array with try/catch and continue in last array index

Tags: java, exception, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am trying to write a program that asks the user for number of size of an array, and interacts with the user to add the numbers. I would like to have a try/catch that displays "Invalid number" if the input is not numeric.

I have done an initial step which is stuck in "Enter a number 1", as below code would show:

```
public static double[] numbersArray (int size) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] arr = new double[size];

    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number "+(i+1));
            String input = sc.next();
            int inputValue = 0;
            try {
                inputValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
                arr[i] = inputValue;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid number");
            }
        }


    }
    return arr;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int size = 4;

    double[] arr = numbersArray(size);


    System.out.println(arr);

}
```

I get as output:

```
How many numbers to enter?
3
Enter a number 1
1
Enter a number 1
2
Enter a number 1
3
Enter a number 1
4
Enter a number 1
```

while I wanted:

```
How many numbers to enter?
3
Enter a number 1
1
Enter a number 2
2
Enter a number 3
3
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Any clue where I am failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break out of the inner loop when you get the value you want

```
while(true) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number "+(i+1));
    String input = sc.next();
    int inputValue = 0;
    try {
        inputValue = Integer.parseInt(input);
        arr[i] = inputValue;
        break; // <-- here
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid number");
    }
}
```

Comment: I just figured out a problem in there. Thanks for pointing out.